# Multiple attributes for one SubElement via Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, soap

I'm writing a SOAP xml file in Python using etree

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="urn:hss">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:add>
      <subscriberList>
        <subscriber name="Sub_Test_Profile_0000000002">
          <uiccList>
            <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000002">
              <profile profile="100Mbps_Data"/>
              <k>7169B9E06940966BF7C4DD3EDD12B06F</k>
              <opc>29EFECFF965CE59587C054FA319D43DC</opc>
            </uicc>
          </uiccList>
        </subscriber>
      </subscriberList>
    </ns2:add>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**I'm trying to figure out how to represent the uicc imsi like the example below with multiple attributes.

```
<uiccList>
       <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000003" profile="100Mbps_Data">
        </uicc>
</uiccList>
```

Comment: This is my current code

   uicc = etree.SubElement(uiccList, "uicc" ,{'imsi':'313:78:' +val})
    # profile = etree.SubElement(uicc, "profile" ,{'profile':'100Mbps_Data'})
    sub = etree.SubElement(uicc, "profile")
    sub.set('profile','100Mbps_Data')                             
    k_tag = etree.SubElement(uicc, "k")

Answer (score 0):

I was making it more difficult than it needed to be. All that was required was a comma between attributes.

uicc = etree.SubElement(uiccList, "uicc" ,{'imsi':'313:78:' +val, 'profile':"100Mbps_Data"})